# How to solve Ambiguous Reference to Member 'sqrt' error?

Tags: swift, sqrt

So I've got this error,

> ambiguous use of sqrt

```
destination = CGPoint(x: flies.position.x-25+CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(50)), 
y: flies.position.y-25+CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(50)))

squaredX = (Int(destination.x)-Int(fly.position.x))*(Int(destination.x)-Int(fly.position.x))

squaredY = (Int(destination.y)-Int(fly.position.y))*(Int(destination.y)-Int(fly.position.y))

distance = sqrt(xy)
```

how would I fix it?

Comment: What is the variable `xy`?

Comment: Press `Cmd + 4` to open the Issue Navigator. Now what are the candidates for this ambiguous reference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that variable xy is one of Double, Float, CGFloat.  These are the three possible functions for sqrt.

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean to do

```
distance = sqrt(squaredX * squaredY)
```

Also, you may need to import Foundation.